# Wso2 API Manager as docker compose handles IP's weirdly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wso2

Using the docker-compose containers published by wso2 for wso2 API Manager available at https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim the address for published API:s behaves weirdly. Some details about the setup:

- The container is running remotely and I access the net where it's located through VPN.
- Carbon, Publisher and Store are all available at the expected IP which is the IP of the Host, let's call it 10.10.1.1
- When an API is published using the Publisher, everything works as expected.

  - In the store, the API is visible in the API overview, but the URL points to:
    https://172.18.0.5:9443/store/apis/info?name=WorldBank&version=1.0.0&provider=admin
    (Using the WorldBank included example)

Changing the provided URL manually to the Host IP (10.10.1.1) works and takes me to the API Specifics page. However, once there, it again lists the API as being published at

http://172.18.0.5:8280/wb/1.0.0

Which is wrong. Again, manually going to the Host IP leads to the published API.

I'm afraid I'm at a loss here, I guess someone who understands how the container is set up could unpack the problem.

Cheers
//J

Answer (score 0):

By default, it takes the container IP address. But you can change those by editing the config files as follows.

- Store URL - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/apim/repository/conf/api-manager.xml#L304
- Gateway Endpoint URL - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/apim/repository/conf/api-manager.xml#L94